# ESLint error in HTML-Files with Angular: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') Occurred while linting

Tags: angular, npm, configuration, eslint, eslintrc

I'm setting up a new project with Angular 15. Therefore I also want ESLint so I installed some Plugins. At the moment it is working fine for .ts-files and also fix errors when I'm saving the file.

Because ESLint is not working for HTML-Files itself, I added eslint-plugin-html. Now when I leave out a specific line (`extends: ['plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended'],`) for the HTML-overrides it is not linting at all - but when added it's throwing the output error. Either ESLint doesn't understand the errors or it is throwing an error-message in output instead fixing them. I'm not sure! The error for line 1 is even thrown when I start with a comment.

My goal is too use ESLint correctly for HTML-Files and not just to turn it off.
Could you please give me a hint how I could debug this or what is the issue?

This is the error in output:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
> Occurred while linting D:\Users\XXX\XXX\src\app\app.component.html:1
> Rule: "indent"

My IDE is VSCode, my package manager is npm and these are my config-files:

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true
  },
  extends: [
    'standard-with-typescript'
  ],
  overrides: [
    {
      files: [
        '*.ts'
      ],
      extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        'plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended',
        'plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates'
      ],
      rules: {
        '@angular-eslint/directive-selector': [
          'error',
          {
            type: 'attribute',
            prefix: 'app',
            style: 'camelCase'
          }
        ],
        '@angular-eslint/component-selector': [
          'error',
          {
            type: 'element',
            prefix: 'app',
            style: 'kebab-case'
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      files: [
        '*.html'
      ],
      plugins: [
        'html'
      ],
      extends: [
        'plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended'
      ],
      rules: {}
    }
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: 'tsconfig.json'
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "catshop",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^7.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "stylelint": "^14.16.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss": "^6.1.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^4.3.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "15.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.46.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.44.0",
    "eslint": "^8.29.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^23.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

node_modules:

[image: @angular-eslint file-structure]

Comment: If there is an error that is thrown at the first line and doesn't make sense, it is very safe that the problem is in the configuration. Either the file itself or in my case it were two different plugins that disturbed each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because many people viewed this question, it seems to be a popular issue.
Therefore, I wanted to share my comment as a solution, so it's more visible.

If there is an error that is thrown at the first line and doesn't make sense, it is very safe that the problem is in the **configuration**. Either the file itself or in my case it were **two different plugins** that disturbed each other.